# How to aggregate multiple child Progress into one master Progress in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, progress, nsprogress

I'm trying to download multiple files simultaneously using NSURLSession in Swift. I want to merge all the download progress status into one as to show 100% when all the files are downloaded. Currently I get 100% for each file download completion, but I need 100% only if all the files are downloaded. How can I achieve this in Swift ?

Here is my DownloadManager Class :

```
class DownloadManager : NSObject, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionDownloadDelegate {

static var shared = DownloadManager()
var task1Progress = 0.00
var task2Progress = 0.00
typealias ProgressHandler = (Float) -> ()

var onProgress : ProgressHandler? {
    didSet {
        if onProgress != nil {
            let _ = activate()
        }
    }
}

override private init() {
    super.init()
}

func activate() -> URLSession {
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "\(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!).background")

    // Warning: If an URLSession still exists from a previous download, it doesn't create a new URLSession object but returns the existing one with the old delegate object attached!
    return URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue())
}

func calculateProgress(session : URLSession, completionHandler : @escaping (Float) -> ()) {
    session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { (tasks, uploads, downloads) in
        let progress = downloads.map({ (task) -> Float in
            if task.countOfBytesExpectedToReceive > 0 {
                return Float(task.countOfBytesReceived) / Float(task.countOfBytesExpectedToReceive)
            } else {
                return 0.0
            }
        })
        completionHandler(progress.reduce(0.0, +))
    }
}


func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {

    if totalBytesExpectedToWrite > 0 {
        if let onProgress = onProgress {
            calculateProgress(session: session, completionHandler: onProgress)
        }

        let progress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
        debugPrint("Download Progress \(downloadTask) \(progress)")

    }
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    debugPrint("Download finished: \(location)")
    try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: location)
}


func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
    debugPrint("Task completed: \(task), error: \(String(describing: error))")
}

private func calculateProgress(session : URLSession, completionHandler : @escaping (Float) -> ()) {
    session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { (tasks, uploads, downloads) in
        let progress = downloads.map({ (task) -> Float in
            if task.countOfBytesExpectedToReceive > 0 {

                if (task.taskIdentifier ==  1) {

                    self.task1Progress = Double(Float(task.countOfBytesReceived) / Float(task.countOfBytesExpectedToReceive))

                } else if (task.taskIdentifier ==  2){

                    self.task2Progress = Double(Float(task.countOfBytesReceived) / Float(task.countOfBytesExpectedToReceive))

                }

                print("pro1 = \(self.task1Progress) pro2 = \(self.task2Progress)")

                if(self.task1Progress>0.0000 && self.task2Progress>0.000) {
                    return Float(min(self.task1Progress  ,self.task2Progress))
                }

                return Float(max(self.task1Progress  ,self.task2Progress))

            } else {

                return 0.0
            }
        })
        completionHandler(progress.reduce(0.0, +))
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you post some code where you update your progress bar ?

Comment: Code had been given in the edited post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dispatchgroup tp achieve the desired behaviour.

To download file you will call shared method of `downloadManager`. Dispatch the downloading operation on dispatchGroup and in notify you will get the callback when all files are downloaded.

Please find example below :

```
func dispatchGroupUsage (completion: CallBack) {
let backgroundQ = DispatchQueue.global(attributes: .qosDefault)
let group = DispatchGroup()

for number in numberOfFilesToBeDownloaded {
  group.enter()
  backgroundQ.async(group: group,  execute: {  
      // call download manager's method to download files
      group.leave()

      })
  }

 group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
   print("All Done"); completion(result: fill)
 }) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

variables for store data and calculate progress

```
var progress: Float = 0
var expectedContentLength: Int64 = 0
var allData: Data = Data()
```

create default session:

```
let defaultConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: defaultConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil
```

download data from url you can call this method as many times as you want

```
func downlod(from url: URL, session: URLSession) {
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url)
    dataTask.resume();
}
```

and you need to implement following delegates

```
URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionDataDelegate 

public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive response: URLResponse, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.ResponseDisposition) -> Swift.Void) {

    progress = 0
    expectedContentLength += response.expectedContentLength
    completionHandler(.allow)
}


public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
    allData.append(data)
    progress = Float(allData.count) / Float(expectedContentLength)
    print("progress - \(progress)")
}
```

don't forget to reset expectedContentLength variable when you starting download, like this

```
expectedContentLength = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [NSProgress](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/progress). It allows you to do exactly what you want.

Each NSURLSessionTask has a [progress](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessiontask/2908821-progress) property (if you are targetting an older OS you can create one yourself).

Then just create a parent NSProgress instance and add each task progress as a child.

Finally, observe the `fractionCompleted` property of NSProgress and update your progress indicator.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement and this is how I managed to fix, for me I had a list of topics and each `topic` had chapters and each `chapter was a file`. So when a topic is downloaded, I had to download its chapters. So here is the catch lets say a topic had `15` files ( I get the number from metadata), there will be `15 download objects and 15 download taskes`, whenever each task fires the progress I handle it in the below function in my view.
The idea is simple each file start from `0.0 to 1.0` to finish, so when all 15 finishes the sum of all progress would be 15.0 that means all download gets finished when `the sum of progress == total number of files`

```
    func handleProgress(percentage:Float){
// Array of files
        let totalFileCount = downloadData.count
        totalPercentageProgress += percentage
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.downloadProgressView.progress = self.totalPercentageProgress / Float(totalFileCount)
        }
    }

-----

    public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64){

        if totalBytesExpectedToWrite > 0 {
            let progressPercentage = Float(totalBytesWritten)/Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
            let progressHandler = getProgressHandlerForTask(identifier: downloadTask.taskIdentifier)
            print(progressPercentage)
            delegate?.handleProgress(progressPercentage)
        }

    }
```